# REST API in flutter

Tags: database, rest, api, flutter

I have a project in which I have a Python database and I have a Flutter ui.
Is there anyway I can use the REST API to connect them? My teammates who do the backend state that their database will use the REST API, so it would be useful if I can do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "python database" ? And where exactly are you having problems with HTTP requests in Flutter?

Comment: https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can easily use REST API's with Flutter.
Dart [offers an `http` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) for easy HTTP request and there are others available on [Dart Pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/).

With the `http` package, you can even integrate your REST API request into the *build tree* very easily using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: http.get('https://your-rest-api-domain.xyz/get-images?amount=5'),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // you can easily work with your request results in here and return a widget
  },
)
```

As [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) mentioned in a comment, Flutter also [provides a cookbook entry on this topic](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/).

Comment: Also how would I send data to my server with this method?

Comment: @Coder [First example](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/378179845420caafbf7a34d47b9c22104753182a/README.md#using) in the README page I linked explains this (use `http.post` instead of `http.get`).

Answer (score 2):

Simple cade for calling REST API and display in a listview.

**Step 1:**
Create a model class like this

```
class ItemSubCat{
  final String ItemCode;
  final String ItemName;

  ItemSubCat(
      {this.ItemCode, this.ItemName});

  factory ItemSubCat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return ItemSubCat(
        ItemCode: parsedJson['ItemCode'],
        ItemName: parsedJson['ItemName']);
  }
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
List<ItemSubCat> parsePosts(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<ItemSubCat>((json) => ItemSubCat.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<ItemSubCat>> fetchsubcat(http.Client client) async {
  var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile||connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {

    final response = await client.get('Your Api Url');
    //print(response.body);
    return compute(parsePosts, response.body);
  } else  {
    Toast.show(message: "Please check your network conenction", duration: Delay.SHORT, textColor: Colors.black);
  }

}
```

**Step 3:**

```
class ItemSubCategory extends StatelessWidget {
  final String ItemCatCode;
  ItemSubCategory({Key key, @required this.ItemCatCode}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData.fallback(),
          title: Text('Category', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<ItemSubCat>>(
          future: fetchsubcat(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? GridViewPosts(items: snapshot.data)
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

**Step 4:**

```
class GridViewPosts extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ItemSubCat> items;
  GridViewPosts({Key key, this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: new GridView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
              return new  Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Divider(height: 0.0),
                  cardDetails(--You pass your data to listitems--),
                ],


              );

            })
    );
  }


}
```

Here you design your widget for a list item (cardDetails)